# sequence of polynomials satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, pointwise-convergence

Can we find a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n \}$, such that $p_n(0) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and for $z \ne 0$,  $p_n(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

My thought: I think yes, we can find such that sequence.
If we can write this polynomial sequence by constructions, then the constant term $p_n(z)$ must be $1$ or approaches to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $p_n(z)-1$ should be a zero function after certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does that argument work? or may be we cannot find such this sequence?

Comment: This is an easy application of Runge's theorem (find a sequence of increasing compact sets $K_n$ that do not contain zero and st $K_n \cup 0$ doesn't disconnect the plane and they exhaust the plane and apply Runge to $f_n=0$ on (a small of a neighborhood of) $K_n$ and $f_n(0)=1$ (or $f_n=0$ on a small neighborhood of $0$ so we get a polynomial $|P_n-f_n|<1/n$ etc (to find K_n think of closed discs on radius $n$ from which you cut a small slice with sides parallel to the $y$ axis of width $1/n$ and add back the segments on the $y$-axis from $\pm 1/n$ to $\pm n$

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help